# Why do bubbles group when one pops?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, bubbles

I was recently observing the way bubbles move as they pop and disappear. I noticed that when bubbles destabilize and pop, the remaining bubbles immediately surrounding it will move to fill its place. I was wondering what the driving cause is here.

At first, I figured that stickiness was the cause. But, I don't think this would be a driving force unless perhaps the bubbles are clustered (i.e. they share at least 1 membrane).

I've also noticed this behavior in groups of individual, non-clustered bubbles. As an introductory physics student, I'm curious: *what causes this phenomenon?*

Comment: You are not specifying what kind of bubbles in what medium. This might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gEGKZRPHqg

Comment: More specifically, bubbles between water and urine (gross, but that's honestly what inspired this question...)

Comment: I found a related question that answers this! http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102306/why-will-two-bubbles-floating-on-water-surface-attract-each-other?rq=1

Strange; I couldn't find one before posting. Voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: You are correct, it is a duplicate so I voted too.

Answer (score 1):

The blubbles exerce pressure forces with their neighboor through the shared membranes. Pressure is higher in blubbles than in free air, when within a field of bubbles it is balanced on each sides of bubble wall... as long as there is a neighbor. When this one pops, the rest of the pack around push towards the empty space.

Comment: This answer addresses bubble clusters, but not individual bubbles as I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The Nature is Smart; it prefers the state with the lowest energy (maximum entropy) in different manifestations.(*surface tension* in this case). Please refer to this link already answered. ([Why does the nature always prefer low energy and maximum entropy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47253/why-does-the-nature-always-prefer-low-energy-and-maximum-entropy))

Comment: I know this much, but I need to know how this is the driving force and what, specifically, is happening with the bubbles.